# What is going on? (Attemp at scraping multiple pages)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
url = "https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=all&q=ferrari"

while url:

    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    name = soup.find_all("div", class_="h3-responsive")

    price = soup.find_all("strong", "h3-responsive")

    next_page = soup.select_one("li.pagination-page>a")

    for price,name in zip(name,price):
        print(name.text,price.text)

    if next_page:
        next_url = next_page.get("href")
        url = urljoin(url,next_url)
    else:
        url = None
```

Nothing is printing for some reason? I've had it running for 5 minutes and still nothing. I've had no error code either so I'm geuinely confused here? If anyone would like to fix this script please do so, if you didn't realize the script is supposed to scrape the name & price as well as every other page/s name and price.

If someone could please re-do the script, and make it also scrape all the other pages, because I have been having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

I've taken some suggestions in and done some editing but the script still won't work.

Comment: Is this your script? Did you write it?

Comment: It's not printing anything because it's not finding anything, and it's not stopping because you've got an infinite loop going on currently which is attempting to scrape the same page over and over. Shift the `if next_page:` block to inside the while, add an `else: url=None` [after the `if` block], and change to `while url` instead of `while True` so if stops when it can't find a next page

Comment: yes I wrote this. It won't scrap all of the other pages though.

Comment: The script below will work if your IP was not already blacklisted by Cloudfront, given you ran that infinite loop a few times. Let me know how it works for you (eventually use a VPN).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the script works, but now my ip is blacklisted because I had that while loop running for over an hour. I'm such an idiot lmao, anyways. Thank you all so much guys! Big thanks to everyone!

Comment: Hey @Driftr95 I tried the script on a new IP address and nothing prints again? Do you know the problem? Script is here: https://pastebin.com/V057zv3a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to get those listings (didn't go for an infinite loop, you're welcome to increase page count and look up for the existence of an element in page (like `next page` url, etc) if you want). There are 10 pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import time as t

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(1, 11)):
    r = s.get(f'https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page={x}')
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    cards = soup.select('div[class="listing-content"]')
    for c in cards:
        title = c.select_one('h2[class="listing-title"]').text.strip()
        location = c.select_one('div[class="listing-location"]').text.strip()
        price = c.select_one('span[class="listing-price"]').text.strip()
        big_list.append((title, location, price))
    t.sleep(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['title', 'location', 'price'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('absurd_cars_uk.csv')
```

This will print out the dataframe, and also save it to disk, as csv:

```
    title   location    price
0   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 4...   Liskeard, Cornwall  £77,500
1   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with ver...   Liskeard, Cornwall  £88,500
2   2020 Ferrari 812 Superfast 6.5 V12 F1 DCT Euro...   Huthwaite, Nottinghamshire  £294,980
3   FERRARI F430 SPIDER Black AUTO Petrol, 2007 Spalding, Lincolnshire  £110,000
4   1982 Ferrari 308 GTSi Coupe Petrol Manual   Newark, Nottinghamshire £73,000
... ... ... ...
130 2001 (X) FERRARI 360 3.6 MODENA F1 2DR  Dinnington, South Yorkshire £64,880
131 2012 Ferrari 458 4.5 Italia Auto Seq 2dr COUPE...   St Albans, Hertfordshire    £139,995
132 1997 Ferrari 456 GTA - 6700 miles   Ripon, North Yorkshire  £59,995
133 2021 Ferrari Roma 3.8T V8 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) ...   York, North Yorkshire   £194,995
134 2015 Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T F1 DCT Euro 6...   Loughborough, Leicestershire    £99,950
135 rows × 3 columns
```

Comment: Is pandas needed to scrape multiple pages?

Comment: No, @Jack9992. It's needed for meaningful display of information, as well as saving it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers Barry. I really appreciate it.
Does this script look okay to you? I've made some editing to it .@Driftr95 recommended changing these things. Here is the script https://pastebin.com/V057zv3a

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Not sure you still need it, but this is specifically in response to</sub>

> <sub>Hey @Driftr95 I tried the script on a new IP address and nothing prints again? Do you know the problem? Script is here: pastebin.com/V057zv3a</sub>

Your [selector](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/) and `find_all`  arguments still don't look quite right. Here's an edited version that uses [`HTMLSession`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) (because I'm not really good at `requests` beyond the very basics, and I couldn't fetch the right html with it):

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time

url = "https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=all&q=ferrari"  
maxTries = 6 # or as you prefer
pageTryCt = 0

while url: 
    print('', end=url)
    response = HTMLSession().get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    # you can use html.parser but you probably need to have html5lib atleast installed

    name = soup.find_all("h2", class_="listing-title") # h2 not div
    price = soup.find_all("strong", class_="h3-responsive") # specify class_

    next_page = soup.select_one("li.pagination-next > a:not(.pagination-disabled)") 
    # class is pagination-next not pagination-page
    # add :not(.pagination-disabled) to exclude disabled button (on last page)

    if name and price: print('')
    for p, n in zip(price, name):
        print(f'{p.text.strip():>10}   {n.text.strip()}') # just to line up

    if next_page:
        next_url = next_page.get("href")
        url = urljoin(url, next_url)

        pageTryCt = 0
        time.sleep(3)
        print('\n') # just adding space to separate pages
    else:
        if pageTryCt < maxTries and len(price+name) == 0:
            pageTryCt += 1 
            print('', end=f'\r[after {45*pageTryCt}sec wait] ')
            time.sleep(45*pageTryCt)
        else: url = None
```

(I print some extra things, and the print format is change a bit for the "rows" and you can change/remove any of that, but please pay attention to the comments.)

It still takes multiple tries for some pages, and you might have to adjust the wait times and `maxTries`, but the output I got was:

```
https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=all&q=ferrari
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £43,998   1997 R FERRARI 456 5.5 GTA 2D 442 BHP
   £79,995   2013 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 2+ 2DR F1 CONVERTIBLE 30/30 MODEL + STUNNING
  £329,995   Ferrari 458 4.5 Spider Auto Seq 2dr
  £189,991   2008 08 FERRARI 430 4.3 SCUDERIA 2D 510 BHP RARE NOVITEC CAR
   £60,990   Ferrari 360 3.6 Spider 2dr Petrol
   £79,950   Ferrari F355 GTS RHD
   £89,950   Ferrari F355 Spider RHD
   £77,850   2011 Ferrari California 4.3 F1 DCT Euro 5 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
  £199,500   2016 Ferrari 488 3.9 SPIDER 2d 660 BHP Convertible Petrol Semi Automatic
  £129,995   2016 Ferrari FF V12 Petrol Automatic
  £129,950   2014 Ferrari FF 2dr Auto HATCHBACK Petrol Automatic
  £268,830   2021 Ferrari F8 Spider Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
  £174,950   2020 Ferrari Portofino GT 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £79,995   1998 Ferrari 355 3.5 BERLINETTA F1 2d 375 BHP Coupe Petrol Automatic
   £74,950   1989 Ferrari 328 GTS 2dr Sports Petrol Manual
  £105,000   1998 Ferrari F355 GTS 2dr Sports Petrol Automatic
  £184,995   2008 Ferrari 430 4.3 Scuderia F1 Euro 4 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
  £152,980   2019 Ferrari Portofino 3.8T V8 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £59,990   2004 04 FERRARI 360 3.6 SPIDER 2D 400 BHP
   £87,000   2006 Ferrari 599 GTB Fiorano F1 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
  £389,830   2020 Ferrari 812GTS 2dr Auto Cabriolet Petrol Automatic
   £77,995   2003 Ferrari 575M F1 Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £119,991   1996 P FERRARI 355 3.5 GTS SPIDER - IMACULATE THROUGHOUT
  £189,950   2017 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £184,980   2019 Ferrari 488 3.9T V8 GTB F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=2
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
  £149,995   Ferrari 488 3.9T V8 GTB F1 DCT (s/s) 2dr
   £64,950   Ferrari 360 Modena F1
  £178,830   2017 Ferrari 488 488 Spider Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £184,830   2016 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £114,900   2017 Ferrari CALIFORNIA T F1 Convertible Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £68,950   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 2D 460 BHP MAGNERIDE! HUGE SPEC!
  £339,850   2019 Ferrari 488 GTB 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
   £89,950   Ferrari 308 GTS RHD
  £183,830   2021 Ferrari Roma Roma Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
   £72,999   2004 Ferrari 360 Spider F1 **Only 27,000 Miles - Stunning Example - FSH**
  £162,495   2018 Ferrari GTC4 LUSSO T 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £269,950   2019 Ferrari 812 Superfast V12 Coupe Petrol Automatic
   £65,000   2007 Ferrari 599 GTB FIORANO COUPE PETROL Manual
  £157,830   2016 Ferrari 488 GTB 488 GTB Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
   £77,990   1983 FERRARI 308 GTSI QUATTROVALVOLE // 2.9L V8 // TARGA // PX SWAP
   £82,980   2013 Ferrari California 4.3 F1 DCT Euro 5 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
   £50,000   1978 Ferrari 308 GT4 DINO PETROL Manual
  £149,830   2013 Ferrari 458 458 Italia Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
    £1,900   Ferrari 488 3.9 Auto GTB BUY FOR ONLY £1900 P/M, FINANCE, PCP WITH BALLOON
   £85,000   1991 Ferrari 348 TS PETROL Manual
   £72,500   2011 Ferrari California 2+ 2dr F1 Petrol
   £89,983   2014 Ferrari California 2+ 2dr F1 Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £169,830   2016 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £84,990   2013 Ferrari California 4.3 2 PLUS 2 2d 490 BHP CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
  £419,830   2022 Ferrari 812 GTS 812 GTS Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=3
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £89,850   Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T Convertible 2dr Petrol F1 DCT Euro 6 (560 ps)
  £139,950   2012 12 FERRARI 458 4.5 ITALIA DCT 2D 570 BHP
   £56,999   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 2D 460 BHP
  £314,830   2019 Ferrari 488 VS 488 Pista Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
  £103,950   2015 Ferrari California V8 T Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £169,980   2017 Ferrari 488 3.9T V8 GTB F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
  £142,880   Ferrari 458 4.5 Spider Auto Seq 2dr Petrol
   £99,991   1999 T FERRARI 355 3.5 GTS TARGA 2D 375 BHP
  £144,990   2013 Ferrari 458 Italia Coupe Petrol Automatic
   £79,995   2003 Ferrari 575M Petrol Manual
  £239,980   2018 Ferrari 812 Superfast 6.5 V12 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automati
   £74,990   2012 Ferrari California 2 Plus 2 Convertible Petrol Manual
  £294,980   2020 Ferrari 812 Superfast 6.5 V12 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automati
  £110,000   FERRARI F430 SPIDER Black AUTO Petrol, 2007
   £73,000   1982 Ferrari 308 GTSi Coupe Petrol Manual
  £129,999   2022 Ferrari 458 4.5 HELE V8 Italia F1 DCT Euro 5 (s/s) 2dr Petrol Automatic
   £98,718   2012 Ferrari FF V12 F1 DCT 4WD Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £152,445   2019 Ferrari Portofino 3.8T V8 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automa
   £79,980   2002 Ferrari 360 3.6 Modena F1 2dr Petrol Automatic
   £98,950   2009 Ferrari F430 F1 Coupe Petrol Manual
  £399,950   2022 Ferrari 812 GTS 2dr Petrol
  £409,995   2022 Ferrari SF90 Stradale 4.0T V8 7.9kWh F1 DCT 4WD Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petr
   £67,500   1986 FERRARI 328 GTS TARGA 3.2 Manual Coupe with 288 GTO BODY
   £89,990   2009 Ferrari F430 F1 Coupe COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £74,950   2010 Ferrari F430 F430 Manual


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=4
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
  £109,800   2015 Ferrari California T 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £89,950   Ferrari F430 Spider F1
   £82,950   Ferrari F430 Spider F1 RHD
   £89,950   1998 S FERRARI 550 5.5 MARANELLO 2D 487 BHP
   £89,990   1999 Ferrari 355 GTS TARGA Petrol Automatic
  £199,950   Ferrari 430 Scuderia RHD
   £87,950   Ferrari California 2 PLUS 2 30
  £164,850   2013 Ferrari 458 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £395,000   1974 Ferrari 365 GT4 Berlinetta Boxer
   £79,500   2013 13 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 2D 490 BHP
  £224,830   2020 Ferrari F8 Tributo Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
  £164,830   2013 Ferrari F12 Berlinetta 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £189,830   2018 Ferrari GTC4 LUSSO GTC4 Lusso Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £169,950   2013 Ferrari 458 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £377,900   2016 Ferrari 458 Speciale 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £399,830   2021 Ferrari SF90 SF90 Stradale 2 Door Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Manual
   £65,000   2019 Ferrari F430 RACING SPEC NOVITEC STYLING Petrol Automatic
   £34,999   1983 Ferrari Mondial Quattrovalvole UK RHD Coupe Petrol Manual
  £149,900   2019 Ferrari Portofino GT 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £166,000   2017 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £77,000   1999 Ferrari F355 GTS 2dr Sports Petrol Automatic
   £82,950   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta RHD
  £259,950   2018 Ferrari 812 SUPERFAST 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £168,950   2019 Ferrari Portofino GT 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £162,850   2017 Ferrari 488 GTB 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=5
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
  £214,550   2021 Ferrari Portofino GT 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £155,830   2018 Ferrari Portofino GT 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £169,950   Ferrari 575M Maranello RHD
  £178,830   2018 Ferrari 488 488 Spider Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £389,830   2021 Ferrari SF90 SF90 Stradale Coupe Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Manual
  £156,900   2016 Ferrari 488 GTB 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £226,400   2022 Ferrari Portofino GT 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £64,995   FERRARI 328 328 GTS Pre ABS 1988
  £199,830   2017 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £94,830   2016 Ferrari California California T Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £108,990   2009 09 FERRARI 430 4.3 SPIDER F1 2D 479 BHP
  £109,995   Ferrari F430 4.3 V8 Spider F1
  £109,950   Ferrari F430 4.3 ( 490bhp ) Spider F1
  £999,990   2008 Ferrari 250 GT California Spyder SWB PETROL Manual
  £147,830   2011 Ferrari 458 458 Italia Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
    £1,000   VALUATION SERVICE ON KIT CARS REPLICA DAX AC COBRA RUSH ULTIMA GTR AK MK GD
   £99,950   Ferrari 308 GTS QV RHD
   £94,994   2015 Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T F1 DCT (s/s) 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
   £57,950   Ferrari 360 Spider F1
  £204,830   2021 Ferrari Roma ROMA S-A 3.8 611BHP Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
   £79,995   2007 Ferrari F430 4.3 Spider F1 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
  £119,950   Ferrari 550 Maranello RHD
   £90,000   2011 Ferrari FF 6.3 Auto Seq 3dr HATCHBACK Petrol Automatic
  £129,995   2005 Ferrari F430 4.3 Spider 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Manual
  £151,999   2018 FERRARI PORTOFINO 3.9 BCA 2D 592 BHP


[after 135sec wait] https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=6
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
  £151,999   2018 FERRARI PORTOFINO 3.9 BCA 2D 592 BHP
  £459,990   2020/20 Ferrari 488 Pista Piloti
   £74,950   Ferrari 360 Spider F1
   £79,995   2003 Ferrari 360M Spider F1 2dr Convertible PETROL Manual
  £279,990   2022 Ferrari F8 2022 22 Ferrari 3.9 V8 F8 Spider Semi Auto Convertible Petrol Au
  £149,995   2011 Ferrari 599 GTB Fiorano F1 2dr COUPE PETROL Manual
   £69,950   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta F1 RHD
  £149,995   Ferrari 458 4.5 Italia Auto Seq 2dr
   £99,950   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta RHD NOW SOLD MORE REQUIRED
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £89,950   Ferrari 550 Maranello RHD
   £71,950   Ferrari 360 Spider
  £168,500   2016 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £159,990   Ferrari Portofino 3.8T V8 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr Petrol
   £69,995   2011 Ferrari California 2+ 2dr F1 Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £92,980   Ferrari 599 6.0 V12 GTB Fiorano F1 2dr Petrol
   £63,950   Ferrari 612 Scaglietti F1
  £199,950   Ferrari F12berlinetta AB
   £76,000   2010 Ferrari California 2+ 2dr F1 CONVERTIBLE Petrol Manual
  £117,450   Ferrari 458 4.5 Italia Auto 2dr Coupe. Very High Spec
   £65,000   2006 Ferrari 612 Scaglietti 2dr F1A COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £69,995   2004 Ferrari 360M Spider F1 2dr Sports Petrol Manual
  £187,000   2018 Ferrari 488 Spider 2dr Auto CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
   £65,950   2005 Ferrari 360
   £49,000   1998 Ferrari 456 GT Petrol Manual


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=7
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
  £130,000   2012 Ferrari 458 Italia 2dr Auto COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £86,000   2013 Ferrari FF 2dr Auto HATCHBACK Petrol Automatic
  £189,830   2021 Ferrari Roma 2dr Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
   £99,950   2002 02 FERRARI 575M 5.7 MARANELLO 2D 515 BHP
  £131,750   2020 Porsche 911 TARGA 4S CONVERTIBLE Petrol Manual
  £269,830   2019 Ferrari 812 SUPERFAST 2dr Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £234,995   Ferrari 488 3.9T V8 GTB F1 DCT (s/s) 2dr
   £74,948   Ferrari 360 3.6 Spider 2dr Petrol
  £178,995   2018 18 FERRARI 488 3.9 GTB 2D 660 BHP
   £74,995   2010 Ferrari California 2+ 2dr F1 CONVERTIBLE Petrol Manual
  £107,991   1998 S FERRARI 355 3.5 GTS TARGA 2D 375 BHP
  £169,830   2016 Ferrari 488 488 Spider Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £169,995   2017 67 FERRARI 488 3.9 GTB 2D 660 BHP
  £174,830   2015 Ferrari 458 Spider 2dr Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £89,890   Ferrari California T
  £165,830   2017 Ferrari 488 GTB 488 GTB Auto Coupe Petrol Automatic
   £72,990   2013 Ferrari California 2+ 2dr F1 Auto Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £273,830   2021 Ferrari F8 F8 SPIDER S-A 3.9 Auto 2 Door Petrol Automatic
  £109,991   2017 61 FERRARI 6.3 FF
   £59,995   2003 Ferrari 360 3.6 Spider 2dr Petrol Manual
  £409,830   2021 Ferrari SF90 SF90 Assetto Fiorano Auto 2 Door Petrol Plug-in Hybrid Automat
   £76,995   2011 Ferrari California 4.3 F1 DCT Euro 5 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
  £189,995   2019 Ferrari 488 3.9T V8 GTB F1 DCT (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
  £269,995   2014 Ferrari 458 4.5 Speciale 2dr Petrol Automatic
   £97,980   2016 Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T F1 DCT Euro 6 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=8
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
  £122,500   2010 Ferrari 599 6.0 V12 GTB Fiorano F1 Euro 4 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £61,995   2009 Ferrari California 4.3 F1 DCT Euro 5 2dr Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £209,830   2004 Ferrari 360 CHALLENGE STRADALE Challenge Stradale Auto 3 door Petrol Automa
  £749,990   2015/15 Ferrari 458 Speciale Aperta
   £64,880   2001 (X) FERRARI 360 3.6 MODENA F1 2DR
  £139,995   2012 Ferrari 458 4.5 Italia Auto Seq 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £59,995   1997 Ferrari 456 GTA - 6700 miles
  £194,995   2021 Ferrari Roma 3.8T V8 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £99,950   2015 Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Auto
  £399,990   2022 Ferrari 812 2022 22 Ferrari 812 6.5 V12 GTS Spider Semi Auto Convertible Pe
   £56,475   1993 Ferrari 348 3.4 ts 2dr Coupe Petrol Manual
  £104,995   2015 Ferrari California T 2dr Auto CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
   £62,950   Ferrari 612 Scaglietti F1
  £185,000   2013 Ferrari F12 Berlinetta 2dr Auto COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £89,995   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta 3.5 V8 Manual 1996 M2.7 /// 39k Miles
   £62,450   2000 Ferrari 360 3.6 MODENA 2d 400 BHP Coupe Petrol Manual
  £120,000   2001 Ferrari 550 LHD manual Petrol
  £119,995   Ferrari Testarossa 4.9 2dr
  £149,995   Ferrari 458 4.5 Spider Auto Seq 2dr
   £79,995   2016 Ferrari F430 4.3 F1 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
  £349,995   Ferrari 488 Pista 3.9T V8 F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr
   £60,000   1989 Ferrari 328 GTS Manual
   £89,990   2006 Ferrari 430 4.3 SPIDER 2d 479 BHP Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £67,995   2003 Ferrari 360 SPIDER F1 - STUNNING - CAPRISTO EXHAUST - BEST ONE FOR SALE? Co
   £74,995   2006 Ferrari F430 4.3 F1 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=9
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
  £139,995   Ferrari 458 4.5 Spider F1 DCT Euro 5 2dr
   £85,000   1986 Ferrari 412 MANUAL PETROL Manual
   £89,995   2013 Ferrari California 4.3 V8 30 F1 DCT 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
  £175,999   2016 Ferrari 488 3.9T V8 Spider F1 DCT Euro 6 (s/s) 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Autom
   £94,000   2000 Ferrari 360M Modena 2dr F1 Coupe Petrol Manual
   £65,000   1996 Ferrari 550 MARANELLO PETROL Manual
  £135,995   2011 Ferrari 458 DCT Coupe Petrol Automatic
  £146,995   2019 69 Ferrari Portofino 3.8T V8 GT Convertible 1 Owner Tour De France Blue F1
   £89,995   2007 Ferrari F430 4.3 Spider F1 DCT 2dr CONVERTIBLE Petrol Automatic
   £76,500   Ferrari F430 4.3 F1 2dr Petrol
  £299,995   1973 Ferrari Dino PETROL Manual
  £197,950   2015 Ferrari 458 Spider - A Outstanding Example - Please Read Our Comments Semi
  £159,995   2014 Ferrari 458 DCT SPIDER Convertible Petrol Automatic
   £42,990   2017 BMW M3 COMPETITION 4dr DCT INDIVIDUAL FERRARI ROSSO RED 1 OF 93+CARBON PACK
   £99,950   1978 FERRARI MCBURNIE REPLICA 250 GTO 250 GTO McBurnie 260z Replica Rebuilt g
   £99,995   Ferrari 456 GTA Coupe
  £169,950   2013 Ferrari F12 Berlinetta Coupe Petrol Automatic
   £99,995   Ferrari 456 GTA Coupe
   £72,950   Ferrari 360 Spider
   £84,950   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta F1 RHD
   £29,995   FERRARI 250 SWB ROADSTER TRIBUTE Z3 - MULTI MILLION LOOKS - MODERN CLASSIC - PX
   £18,995   2016 66 BMW 435D XDRIVE M SPORT GRAN COUPE 313PS + FERRARI RED + INDIVIDUAL
   £44,995   1997 Ferrari 456 GTA RHD
   £79,950   Ferrari F430
   £80,000   2008 Ferrari 599 GTB FIORANO HGTE PETROL Manual


https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=10
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
  £100,000   1976 Ferrari 308 VETRORESINA PETROL Manual
   £65,000   2020 Audi RS4 Avant 2.9 TFSI V6 Tiptronic quattro Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr ESTATE Petrol
  £379,990   2021/21 Ferrari SF90 Stradale
   £94,950   Ferrari F355 GTS F1 RHD
   £87,950   Ferrari F430 F1 Spider
  £104,995   1999 Ferrari 355 F1 GTS 2dr Petrol Automatic
   £76,950   Ferrari California 2 PLUS 2
   £99,995   2020 Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T F1 DCT Euro 6 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £69,995   2005 Ferrari 612 5.7 Scaglietti FI 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £66,666   Ferrari 360 Modena F1 ROSSO SEATS. F430 WHEELS. FULLY LOADED. FULLY RESTORED. LOOKS THE BEAST
    £3,800   Ferrari 295 GTB
   £75,000   Ferrari F355
   £74,500   *FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3L V8 – ROSSO CORSA – 22K MILES– FFSH - IMMACULATE* ** WARRANTY 25/10/2023**
   £16,500   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta Replica
   £33,000   ☆BMW 340i individual ☆FERRARI RED F30 like M3 F80. 3 SERIES
  £119,895   2017 McLaren 570S V8 SSG Convertible Petrol Manual
  £167,000   2020 Ferrari Portofino T V8 Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £167,000   Ferrari 3.8T V8 Convertible 2dr Petrol F1 DCT (s/s) (600 ps)


[after 225sec wait] https://www.gumtree.com/search?search_category=cars&search_location=uk&q=ferrari&page=10
   £88,500   2011 61 FERRARI FF 6.3 V12 4WD 660bhp with very high factory specification
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
  £100,000   1976 Ferrari 308 VETRORESINA PETROL Manual
   £65,000   2020 Audi RS4 Avant 2.9 TFSI V6 Tiptronic quattro Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr ESTATE Petrol
  £379,990   2021/21 Ferrari SF90 Stradale
   £94,950   Ferrari F355 GTS F1 RHD
   £87,950   Ferrari F430 F1 Spider
  £104,995   1999 Ferrari 355 F1 GTS 2dr Petrol Automatic
   £76,950   Ferrari California 2 PLUS 2
   £99,995   2020 Ferrari California 3.8 V8 T F1 DCT Euro 6 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £69,995   2005 Ferrari 612 5.7 Scaglietti FI 2dr COUPE Petrol Automatic
   £77,500   2011 11 FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3 2 PLUS 2 Auto 460bhp only 14,750 miles in White
   £66,666   Ferrari 360 Modena F1 ROSSO SEATS. F430 WHEELS. FULLY LOADED. FULLY RESTORED. LOOKS THE BEAST
    £3,800   Ferrari 295 GTB
   £75,000   Ferrari F355
   £74,500   *FERRARI CALIFORNIA 4.3L V8 – ROSSO CORSA – 22K MILES– FFSH - IMMACULATE* ** WARRANTY 25/10/2023**
   £16,500   Ferrari F355 Berlinetta Replica
   £33,000   ☆BMW 340i individual ☆FERRARI RED F30 like M3 F80. 3 SERIES
  £119,895   2017 McLaren 570S V8 SSG Convertible Petrol Manual
  £167,000   2020 Ferrari Portofino T V8 Convertible Petrol Automatic
  £167,000   Ferrari 3.8T V8 Convertible 2dr Petrol F1 DCT (s/s) (600 ps)
```